# Properties of rest-frame spinors

Tags: inertial-frames, dirac-equation, spinors

The four rest-frame spinors ${\displaystyle u^{(s)}\left({\vec {0}}\right),}$ ${\displaystyle \;v^{(s)}\left({\vec {0}}\right)}$ satisfy
$${\displaystyle ({p\!\!\!/}-m)u^{(s)}\left({\vec {p}}\right)=0}$$

$${\displaystyle ({p\!\!\!/}+m)v^{(s)}\left({\vec {p}}\right)=0}$$
In the rest frame, since ${\displaystyle {p\!\!\!/}\equiv \gamma ^{\mu }p_{\mu }}=\gamma ^{0}m$, they reduce to
$${\displaystyle (\gamma ^{0}-1)u^{(s)}\left({0}\right)=0}$$

$${\displaystyle (\gamma ^{0}+1)v^{(s)}\left({0}\right)=0}$$

But in A Zee QFT in a nutshell he mentioned that (II.6.4)
$${\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{0}u(0)=1 \quad \& \quad {\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{i}u(0)=0$$
**how to show the above without using any perticular basis** like Dirac basis or Weyl (chiral) basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${\displaystyle (\gamma ^{0}-1)u\left({0}\right)=0}\Rightarrow \gamma ^{0}u\left({0}\right)=u\left({0}\right)$$
If we conjugate transpose ${\displaystyle (\gamma ^{0}-1)u\left({0}\right)=0}$ we get
$$u\left({0}\right)^\dagger (\gamma ^{0\dagger}-1)=0$$
$$u\left({0}\right)^\dagger\gamma ^{0}\gamma ^{0} (\gamma ^{0}-1)=0$$
$${\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{0} (\gamma ^{0}-1)=0$$
$${\overline {u}}(0) (1-\gamma ^{0})=0$$
$${\overline {u}}(0) (\gamma ^{0}-1)=0$$
$${\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{0}={\overline {u}}(0)$$
So now
$${\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{0}u(0)={\overline {u}}(0)u(0)=1$$
$$\begin{aligned}
{\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{i}u(0)&={\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{0}\gamma ^{0}\gamma ^{i}u(0)\\
&=-{\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{0}\gamma ^{i}\gamma ^{0}u(0)\\
&=-{\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{i}u(0)
\end{aligned}$$
$$\Rightarrow {\overline {u}}(0)\gamma ^{i}u(0)=0$$